# How to remove an item with Angular NgRx based on the ID of a string?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to implement a `"removeCustomerById(id:string)"` function. I'm new to NgRx and not sure about how to implement it. Here is my approach:

**Actions**

```
// Delete Customer ========================
export const deleteSingleCustomerAction = createAction(
 ActionTypes.DeleteCustomerAction,
 props<{ customerID: string }>()
);
export const deleteSingleCustomerActionSuccess = createAction(
  ActionTypes.DeleteCustomerSuccessAction,
);
```

**Reducer**

```
// Delete Customer ========================
on(deleteSingleCustomerAction, (state, {customerID}) => ({
 ...state,
 loading:   true,
 customers: state.customers.filter(element => element.id !== customerID)
})),
```

**CustomerTable Compoenent: delete function**

```
onDeleteClick(element: CustomerElement): void {
 this.store.dispatch(deleteSingleCustomerAction({customerID:element.id}));
}
```

I have a correct UI behavior here. Selected elements are removed by clicking the "Remove" button.

The problem is that **my backend has not changed**, and if I refresh my application, all deleted items are back again. I already have a function in my service for sending delete requests.

**CustomerService**

```
removeCustomberById(id: string) {
 // REST API CALL delete item by id
}
```

The question is how and when to call `removeCustomberById(id: string)`

Must it be done as an NgRx Effect? Because it is a side effect? Or do I need to call `removeCustomberById(id: string)` before dispatching?

Like this prototype:

```
 onDeleteClick(element: CustomerElement): void {
  //REST delete
  deletedCustomer =  this.customerService -> REST delete Request element
  //dispatch
  this.store.dispatch(deleteSingleCustomerAction({customerID: 
  deletedCustomer.id}));
}
```

In my approach I decided to implement an effect:

```
deleteCustomersActionEffect = createEffect(
 () => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.DeleteCustomerAction),
  mergeMap((customerID: string) => //<-this is wrong
  this.customerService.removeCustomberById(customerID)
    .pipe(
      map((customers: CustomerDTO[]) => (
        {
          type:    ActionTypes.DeleteCustomerSuccessAction,
          payload: customers
        }
      )),
    )),
  tap(() => console.log(ActionTypes.DeleteCustomerAction + " - Action 
 Dispatched"))
 ),
);
```

But this doesn't work, because the `customerID` of  `mergeMap((customerID: string)` is an `[OBJECT]` instead of a `string` with the `id`. I don't really understand how to build such an effect.

**How I can get the correct string id inside of my effect?**

Comment: Should be mergeMap(({customerID}) => …

Comment: MikeOne is correct, although I've provided some details below. MikeOne, may I suggest that giving some context is better than simply giving an answer with no explanation as to why it works :-) just a word to the wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there! You do indeed want a side effect here, and I would recommend that your reducer react to the `DeleteCustomerSuccessAction` (that way you make sure your API has deleted the customer before deleting it in the frontend) as opposed to the `DeleteCustomerAction` (which, in my opinion, should only have the Effect react to it).

The solution lies in that infamous `mergeMap` of yours. Have a think about what exactly you are receiving there. What are you piped onto here? What does the previous step in the pipe give you?

...

An action! You receive the full `Action` as opposed to just its payload.

Hope that puts you on the right track...